# Why have the badge icons lost spacing around them?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

For some reason, my badges just lost a lot of their spacious weight

[image]

It's not normal for a healthy badge to be that skinny. I'm getting a little bit worried - what have the SE staff done to make my badges so unhealthy? Are they not getting their daily dose of Vitamin Skeet?

[image]

I am appalled by the fact that, of all communities, Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange seem to be the most plagued with these destitute badges. I ask, why does this not happen in other communities such as Information Security or Code Golf?

The media portrays a Stack Overflow, a "popular" badge as one that is sickeningly perfect; this is not the way badges are meant to look! All badges are beautiful no matter how they look - no badge can ever be perfect. We should not let the media prevent these poor badges from getting their SE recommended daily amount of Vitamin Skeet, the most important vitamin in a healthy badge!

---

If that made no sense at all to you, badges don't have as much spacing around them as they should, [image]. I'm tagging this as a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug), because I don't think this is intentional.

This happens on Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange, but not other SE websites such as Code Golf or Information Security.

Comment: I think the padding on `.badge, .badge-tag` be changed to `padding: .4em .8em .4em .8em;`. On `.badge1, .badge2, .badge3` the `margin-left:3px;` is missing.

Comment: To answer the question in your title: yes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should be fixed now. You were correct, the culprit was a [vitamin Skeet deficiency](https://twitter.com/kjbeavers/status/677543492558655488). If you see any more sick badges, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you, I am very happy to hear that these sick badges have been cured of their deficiency of Vitamin Skeet

Comment: Now badges on other sites seem to have too much left spacing.  [Here's my profile badges on Aviation.SE](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ISwmc.png).  Firefox 42.0, Windows 8.1

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom pushing a tweak soon.